# CSS - some ID selector is not working

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why using first selector is not working and style is ignored and second one works?
I double checked the typo so it is not human error..
I'm wondering when browser reads CSS it does not like that particular text for some reason?

http://jsfiddle.net/cyvv3efs/2/

```
<div id='10305a09-55f0-4a3c-a710-2f0449ae7d44'>not work</div>

<div id='f9392ae0-954a-4d87-baf6-127d9c253877'>works</div>

#10305a09-55f0-4a3c-a710-2f0449ae7d44
{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height:20px;
}

#f9392ae0-954a-4d87-baf6-127d9c253877
{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: You have some invalid "-" in your selector names.

see:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: You have some invalid "-" in your selector names.

see:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: You have some invalid "-" in your selector names.

see:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` cannot start with a number. Try adding a letter before and it should work.

[image]

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) as well.